# Querying customer change log for earliest record to determine the user that created the record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to report on which users created a given record in our customer table. Unfortunately it only shows the last user to modify the record. There is a change log though so I need to pull the earliest record for a given customer and pull the id of the change user.

So I have this:

```
SELECT min(ca.archive_date),  
ca.cust_no,  
ca.change_user  
FROM mi_masdb.dbo.customer_archive ca  
GROUP BY ca.cust_no
```

but it won't pull the change user because there are multiple change users for each cust_no. I just need it to pull the change user associated with the earliest archive date for each cust_no.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way of doing this uses `row_number()`:

```
SELECT ca.*  
FROM (SELECT ca.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_no ORDER BY archive_date) as seqnum
      FROM mi_masdb.dbo.customer_archive ca 
     ) ca 
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

The following might be faster:

```
select ca.*
from mi_masdb.dbo.customer_archive ca join
     (select ca2.cust_no, min(ca2.archive_date) as min_archive_date
      from mi_masdb.dbo.customer_archive ca2
     ) ca2
     on ca2.cust_no = ca.cust_no and ca2.min_archive_date = ca.archive_date;
```

Comment: The partition by worked perfectly. I had to modify slightly to put it into my working version, but that concept works the best with the other joins I have to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add change_user column in group by clause. refer below

```
SELECT min(ca.archive_date),  
ca.cust_no,  
ca.change_user  
FROM mi_masdb.dbo.customer_archive ca  
GROUP BY ca.cust_no, ca.change_user
```